# android - Determine object type from string variable

Tags: java, android, string, object

I have class with following constructor.
I have few other classes with similar constructors.

```
obnova=new obnova(context,db,this,baz);
```

Can I determine on runtime which object will be created depending on string variable?

like this:

```
String obn="obnova";
obn=new obn(context,db,this,baz);`
```

so I want to create object obnova.

Comment: Are all the created classes of the same base type? (I.e., Do all the classes  you want to create in this method use the same parent class/interface?)

Comment: You should create a Factory pattern for creating these objects maybe.

If that doesn't work for you check this getClass().getName(). It is going to give you string which you can compare. But I don't recommend this.

Comment: @NikG No they do not use the same parent class but they have similar constructor, so I can create any tpe of those classes with simple change of one word - `obnova obnova=new obnova(context,db,this,baz);` or `okov okov= new okov(context,db,this,baz);` etc...

Comment: @Nikola Milutuinovic I don't think I could use .getName 'cause I don't have an object to compare with. I intent to create object with particular name.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string, representing a class name you can create an object of that class using

```
Class clzObnova = (Obnova)Class.forName("my.package.obnova");
Obnova obnova = clzObnova.newInstance()
```

This is if your class has a noargs constructor. If your constructor has arguments you first get a constructor by `Class.getDeclaredConstructor()`.
I don't remember the details check the docs

Comment: The problem remaines the same. In this statement `Obnova obnova = clzObnova.newInstance()` "Obnova" is value of a string so i don't have it before creating an object.